# How can I pass different SwiftUI views in my model?

Tags: swiftui

New to SwiftUI and I cannot find a way to pass multiple views in my model which populates the **List** in the **NavigationStack**.

(Below I have placed all my code into one file to make it easier to examine)

I populate **List** from **MainMenuFramework**, which would hold the title, graphic, and eventually a subMenu to go to for each **List** element. i.e. SubView1, SubView2, and so on.

When within the **MainMenuFramework** I try to add `let subMenu : View` I first am told to add it as `any View`. But then I have to make **MainMenuFramework** conform to the Equatable protocol. And from there I am told that **MainMenuFramework** has to conform to Hashable, even though it is.

The real problem is that I am falling deeper into the well and am too new to understand what is happening. Is there perhaps a way to pass a pointer to the subviews?

I don't just want the answer, I'd like to understand the process as well.

Thank you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                List(MainMenuData.mainMenuFramework) { menuItem in
                    NavigationLink {
//                      menuItem.subMenu
                    } label: {
                        ListCell(framework: menuItem)
                    }


                }
                .navigationTitle("Main Menu")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListCell: View {
    
    let framework : MainMenuFramework
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                Image(systemName: framework.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
            Text(framework.description)
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.leading, 30)
        }
        .listRowInsets(.init(top: 10,
                     leading: 10,
                     bottom: 10,
                     trailing: 10))

    }
}

struct FrameworkTitleView: View{

    let framework : MainMenuFramework
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: framework.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            Text(framework.name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                .scaledToFit()
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.6)
        }
        .padding()
    
    }
}

struct MainMenuFramework: Hashable, Identifiable {
        

    let id              :   Int
    let name            :   String
    let imageName       :   String
    let urlString       :   String
    let description :   String
}


struct MainMenuData {

    static let mainMenuFramework = [
        
        MainMenuFramework(
            id: 001,
            name: "Setup",
            imageName: "list.clipboard",
            urlString: "",
            description: "Setup"),
        
        MainMenuFramework(
            id: 002,
            name: "Account",
            imageName: "person.circle",
            urlString: "",
            description: "Account Settings"),
        
        MainMenuFramework(
            id: 003,
            name: "Help",
            imageName: "questionmark.circle",
            urlString: "",
            description: "Support")

    ]

}
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the detail view 1")
    }
}

struct DetailView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the detail view 2")
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited as per comments from jnpdx

- Create an enum that maps out which subview to go to
- Add an additional property within my MVVM structure (gotoView) that correlates to the correct subview within the enum above

```
enum SubView {
    case detail1, detail2
}

struct MainMenuFramework: Hashable, Identifiable {

    let id              :   Int
    let name            :   String
    let imageName       :   String
    let urlString       :   String
    let description     :   String
    let gotoView        :   SubView
}

struct MyListView: View {
    var choice : SubView
  
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        switch choice {
            case .detail1:
                DetailView1()
            case .detail2:
                DetailView2()
            // future cases mapped out here in this one view
            }
    }
}
```

and where I am populating List:

```
    List(MainMenuData.mainMenuFramework) { menuItem in
        NavigationLink {
            MyListView(choice: menuItem.gotoView)
        } label: {
           ListCell(framework: menuItem)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that using `AnyView` is generally a bad idea and can lead to all sorts of unintended side effects. Watch Demystify Swift from WWDC for information on why.

Comment: I believe you, but then that leaves me back at square one. How can I pass different subviews in my MVVM? Placing a view directly in my MVVM struct, that populates List, is like jumping into a endless pit

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but in general, you would not "pass subviews". Instead, render your view based on some sort of state -- an `enum` for example.

Comment: I'm not going to write this as a whole answer, so forgive the inline code: `switch viewType { case .subview1: SubView1() case .subview2: SubView2() }` etc

Comment: As I see it, that creates extra long, and un-reusable code if you're trying to write an app with multiple submenus on many levels. So I can store every aspect that goes into my List; Text, Image, Description, Label, etc. in my MVVM. But I can't seem to place the associated subview in the same struct.

Comment: Either way, you must have code that represents your state and then builds a View from it -- nothing about the strategy is "un-reusable" compared to another strategy.

Comment: @jnpdx You gave me the right answer in telling me to watch that video. It appeared to address the very issue I was having. Have modified my answer to reflect that. I hope I understood it properly, and that I am avoiding AnyView. Thank you !

Comment: Glad it pointed you in the right direction.